# axios delete API does not work (with JSON server)

Tags: reactjs, axios, json-server

I am trying to delete record from db.json through JSON server delete endpoint. db.json content is like below:

```
{
 "todoList": [{
  "todoText": "Second todo",
  "key": "2"
   }, {
  "todoText": "Third todo",
  "key": "3"
   }]
}
```

I tried following code but it is not working. i get 404 error.

```
const resp = await axios.delete('http://localhost:3001/todoList?key=3') OR

const resp = await axios.delete('http://localhost:3001/todoList/', {
   params: { "key": key }
})
```

following works if i add id property in above json (with same value like key):

```
 await axios.delete('http://localhost:3001/todoList/' + key)
```

Is there a way to make it working without id property?

Comment: That's just how json-server works https://github.com/typicode/json-server#plural-routes

Comment: Maybe you could add a custom route https://github.com/typicode/json-server#add-custom-routes